# Reference member binds to a temporary object whose life-time would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following compiler error trying to initialize a `Context`:

> Reference member 'context' binds to a temporary object whose life-time would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object

. What temporary `object` is the compiler referring to? `onEventInternal` is `static` so the lifecycle can't be shorter

```cpp
class Event {};

class Context {
    Context(int width, int height, void(*eventCallback)(Event&)) {}
};

class App {

    App(int w, int h): context{w, h, onEventInternal } {} // Error here! 

    static void onEventInternal(Event& event) {
        //event handling
    }
    
private:
    const Context& context;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In the initialization section of your constructor:

```
context{w, h, onEventInternal }
```

This constructs a temporary `Context` object, stores a reference to this object in the `context` class member. So far so good. Then, as soon as the constructor returns this temporary object gets destroyed, leaving `context` as a reference to a destroyed object. Any subsequent use of this class member will result in undefined behavior.

`context` is a reference. It is not an object. That's what a reference means: it's a reference to some other object, somewhere.

The object that a reference refers to is a completely different and independent object.

You must construct this reference to refer to some other, existing object.

Your constructor does that, but it's a temporary object, and your compiler is smart enough to figure it out and warn you that you are at a high risk of [demons flying out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

You will need to either change the class member to a standalone object, and not a reference, or pass a reference to the constructor, and have the constructor set the class member to the passed-in reference to some other object.

Answer (score 1):

> What temporary object is the compiler referring to?

You're constructing a temporary `Context` in member initializer list and binding it to reference member `context`. The temporary will be destroyed immediately and left `context` dangled.

```
App(int w, int h): context{w, h, onEventInternal } {}
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// constructing a temporary Context and bind to context
```

[class.base.init#8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#8)

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member in a
> mem-initializer is ill-formed. [Example 5:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A() : v(42) { }   // error
>   const int& v;
> };
> ```
>
> — end example]